# c# Download File from URL - not working

Tags: c#, url, download, webclient

Im trying to get my C# program to download a file from an address (http://example.com/test.txt, obvs this isn't the real address)

I setup the Webclient and use DownloadFile() as shown:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string filename =  @"C:\test_dwl.txt";
client.DownloadFile("http://example.com/test.txt", filename);
```

I know what the test.txt file should contain. However after I run my c# code, and then open the C:\test_dwl.txt it doesn't contain the expected data.

It just says:

***This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support***

What confuses me is why it is mentioning Javascript?? I'm sure the file can be downloaded directly. If I enter the address directly into chrome (http://example.com/test.txt) - it downloads the correct file.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or do I need to use a different method in C# to download these files.

Thanks

EDIT: this is what chrome dev tools show

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("e99c963ef2ec3e7d2f9e25eb2b02827b");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="http://example.com/test.txt?ckattempt=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

How can I use this in c#??

Comment: Well, that url does not point to the file you think it should."Am I doing something wrong here?" --- you're requesting the wrong url presumably.

Comment: No Im sure it is the right link. Like I said, entering the url into chrome works. In fact Ctrl+Click of the link in Visual Studios opens a tab in visual studio which has the right data????

Comment: Check the chrome developer tools (hit f12), network tab, when you do that. It's proabbly downloading a js file that does some stuff then downloads the actual text file.

Comment: Im not sure how to use chrome dev tools? Could you guide me roughly. Also is it possible to embed Javascript into a c# program if thats what they are asking for?

Comment: Try navigating to that URL with Chrome dev tools open. Take a look at any network activity and you will likely see that the server probably serves up some HTML (containing the text you see) with JavaScript when you request the "file". That JS then redirects you to the file you are trying to download.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the code  below and process :

In Js File :

```
var file_name = response.value[0]["name"];
var downloadurl = response.value[0]"@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"];
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------//

```
function HandleIT(downloadurl,file_name) {
    PageMethods.ProcessIT(downloadurl,file_name, onSucess, onError);
    function onSucess(result) {
        alert(result);       
    }
    function onError(result) {
        alert('Something wrong.');
    }
}
```

In  Code Behind  us the Webmethod :

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string ProcessIT(string downloadURL, string file_name)
        {            
            // Create a new WebClient instance.
            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            string  path = @"c:\";
            string path_n_name = path + file_name; 
            // Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(downloadURL, path_n_name);
            return "SUCCESS";
        }
```

Hope it works for you...!

Answer (score 0):

From a quick google search, I see that the file you are trying to download is hosted on a free host like Byethost. Therefore you would need more effort to download this resource than simply using a HTTP Client..
Usually free hosts insert JavaScript onto pages like this to prevent bots from downloading files.
`WebClient` is just a client that implements HTTP spec and nothing else.

You have two options :

1. Switch to a (paid) host with proper file hosting support.
   Bandwidth doesn't come free. You can try GitHub for free you don't mind the file being public. (Of course, you can use cryptic names and have it hidden from search engines)
2. Use a headless browser for downloading.
   A headless browser is basically a browser without a UI but would support loading HTML and running JavaScript on the DOM.
3. Reverse engineer their algorithm.
   Since you prefer to hide the details, I can't help much. But the html file from the debug tools has a script which uses the [slowAES](http://code.google.com/p/slowaes/) library to decrypt the access key to the file.
   `slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)` is using `function(cipherIn,mode,key,iv)`, so
   `c` is the ciperIn, i.e. the bytes to decrypt,
   `2` is the modeOfOperation parameter, which is CBC in this case,
   `a` is the key, and
   `b` is the iv, aka the initialization vector.
   You can get the variables `a`, `b` and `c` using Regular Expressions or just using the `String.IndexOf(string, int)` to get the index of the string `("` for the only 3 occurrences (which are during assignment of varibles a,b,c) and the next 32 chars after them i.e. `String.Substring(index,32)` for all the 3 occurrences. And then you can probably use a hex-to-bytes converter and pass them to the `RijndaelManaged`'s functions to decrypt the key, then convert the bytes returned back to hex and pass the appropriate cookies in the HTTP Cookie header (for every time the `document.cookie` function is being used) and finally get a valid link for the file when you send a request second time with the original URL being appended with ?ckattempt=1
   I've not explored into how the [testcookie](https://github.com/kyprizel/testcookie-nginx-module) nginx module (used by Byet Host to mitigate bots) works so I don't know if my method would work for the second time in case it uses a smart script generator.
   I don't have pseudo-code as of now. I might edit the answer later with pseudo-code, but I guess that might potentially violate your ToS agreement with Byet Host. So host it on GitHub.